# VBA Outlook loop through my colleagues tasks

Tags: vba, search, outlook, task, share

I found how to assign tasks to my colleagues.
Is it possible to loop through my colleagues tasks with filter on project name, so I could monitorate tasks status?
In a team project we assign tasks to each other, and the project manager could in one click see important tasks, their status, due date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to get a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example, to get the shared tasks folder you can use the following code:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
  Call ShowTasks(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 

Sub ShowTasks(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim TaskFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set TaskFolder = _ 
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _ 
 (myRecipient, olFolderTasks) 
 TaskFolder.Display 
End Sub
```